# Make a tetrahedral pyramid with these puzzle pieces.

Tags: geometry, visual, mechanical-puzzles

Recently on a local [fair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair) (*mela*) I bought this puzzle from a magic-stall. 
It contains the following parts (each part is rigid, inflexible)

[image: dismantled]

**Fig- 1** : Dismantled pieces in 1 set.

It contains :

- rod like piece, containing 4 balls in a straight line:  such set 2 pieces.
- Rectangular piece with 6 (= 3 X 2 ) balls, The arrangement of balls is square type : Such set 2 pieces.
- a triangular tray.

All balls are equal in diameter. The balls of a single piece could not be detached or bent.

The whole thing is to be assembled into a pyramid (more specifically regular tetrahedron) , as follows:

[image: Assembled]

**Fig- 2**: What to attain. The regular tetrahedron shown from different viewpoints.

Assembled piece shows 4 balls at each edge.

..............................

Hints:

.................................................

> 1. completely geometric puzzle.

.....

> 2. No lateral thinking required.

.....

> 3. The completed piece would look like a stack of marbles or oranges.

.......

> 4.  the model on hand will make the game much easier.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The way to assemble this is in the following order :

> -  take one of the long 1x4 pieces.

...

> - take one of the 2x3 pieces, and sit it on top of the first piece so that 3 balls appear on each side  of the single rod.

...

> - take the 2nd 2x3 piece, rotate 90 degrees from   the other one, and place on the top of the prior 2x3.

...

> - Place  the last 1x4 on top of the contraption. This structure, when tilted to any side 45 degrees, will give you the final product.

... ... ... ... ...

Picture to follow

> [image: Picture to follow]

Comment: Upvote! Excellent answer!  It would be great if you could _hide_ parts of your answer until hovered over, so that readers don't see the solution before having a chance to try it themselves.

Comment: ya this is correct solution.

Comment: @BrettFromLA hmm it is called spoiler. Okay I'm editing answer; which may be approved/ improved/ disapproved as per moderators' discretion.